# Race Condition in Store between `render` and `componentDidMount`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Is it safe to set up Store listeners in `componentDidMount` without at the same time also calling `setState` or `forceUpdate` (and thus triggering an immediate re-render)?

In React the common examples seem to be to synchronise Store state in `getInitialState` or pull Store data in the `render` before listening, and then start listening in `componentDidMount`.  What prevents a Store change being missed in the interval between the render and setting up the listener in `componentDidMount`?

If a child component takes a synchronous action in its `componentDidMount` that changes the store wont this change be missed by the parent component?

If the child component emits an asynchronous action in `componentDidMount` is there any chance this could change the Store in a way that is missed by the parent component?

Are there any gaps in the React component life-cycle where asynchronous events can get in?

Coming from a background in preemptive asynchronous programming the lack of explicit synchronisation guards in javascript, while often unnecessary in co-operative asynchronous programming, really make me uneasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing and digging through the source code I've come to the conclusion that asynchronous events cannot be triggered anywhere in the initial component lifecycle (`getInitialState` -> `componentWillMount` -> `render` -> Children -> `componentDidMount`).

Synchronous events called from child components which can change the Store will definitely resolve before the parent can call `componentDidMount` and will lead to the view and data becoming de-synchronised.

I've come to the conclusion that the only reason not to register Store listeners in `componentWillMount` is because they shouldn't be run on servers in isomorphic applications.  This to my mind isn't sufficient reason because it registers the listeners out of document order (this can have performance implications) and risks missing synchronous changes to the Store during initial render.  It's also conceptually the wrong place to do it.

I'm planning to register my listeners in `componentWillMount` wrapped with the browser test:

```
componentWillMount: function () {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    // register listener in browser only
  }
}
```

Comment: OR setup a static method on each component which takes the store and params from your url and then collects the stores methods (which will return promises).

Comment: @limelights I don't entirely understand your comment but I think you might be talking about AJAX Stores whereas I'm talking about Flux Stores.

Comment: Common practice with flux stores is to have a 'getStateFromStores()` or similar inside the function called from your listener - to get *state* from the stores. That way, if you missed x update cycles in the stores, your getting will fetch the latest state from stores, meaning with all changes processed, and then re-render the latest state.

Comment: @wintvelt That way madness lies.  You're assuming an update will occur after the one you have missed, and in a timely fashion.

Comment: The root cause of the problem is probably elsewhere: in having a child component fire a store change somewhere in the child's initial render cycle. IMHO this could and should be avoided. Let the render cycle of component + all children finish before having any component do something to trigger store update. OK for stateful children to read from store. NOT OK for stateful children to change the stores. Move those calls up in component tree and pass results as props to children.

Comment: @wintvelt No, the root cause of the problem is the race condition.  You're suggesting work-arounds to avoid triggering the problem, rather than actually solving the problem.  The only guaranteed events you have in a child component is it's initial render so it has to do any required work at that stage.  Suppose you have a child component that fetches data by AJAX which updates the store.  This is fine since AJAX is asynchronous and so will fire after.  Then upgrade your program with an AJAX proxy-cache and now your AJAX request may become synchronous, your site breaks.

Comment: I see what you mean. If you are sure the child call is synchronous, than you could avoid. But if you are not sure if your AJAX call will be async or synchronous, then indeed you run into trouble. Thanks for explaining. Found [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2763) discussion on github, which may be related